# React widget number picker doen not accept keyboard minus char

Tags: reactjs, react-widgets

Is there  way to stop the Riact Widget NumberPicker from filtering out the keyboard minus char?

You can press down on the little roller buttons and the number goes down to a negative, but why does it filter the minus keystroke?

Comment: <NumberPicker 
    min={0}
  />
Maybe you shoud try this!

Comment: I had it set to `min={0}` and `min={-999}` and stil did not accept a keyboard entered  `-` minus. Dont know why the widget is filtering the minus keystroke. Bit of a bug if you ask me.

Comment: Idk really, never used that. Post issue on their GitHub ^^